# unrecognized name error with aliases and subquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, inner-join

```
SELECT 
    stations.station_id,
    stations.name,
    number_of_rides AS number_of_rides_starting_at_station
FROM
    (SELECT 
         start_station_id, 
         COUNT(*) number_of_rides
     FROM
         `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` AS trips 
     GROUP BY
         start_station_id) AS station_num_trips
INNER JOIN
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations` AS stations
      ON trips.start_station_id = stations.station_id 
ORDER BY 
    number_of_rides DESC
```

I create aliases for the table names so that the query can identify the tables being used for the `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Your join can’t join on trips, or that join should move up into station_num_trips. trips is your unrecognised name

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT 
 stations.station_id,
 stations.name,
 number_of_rides AS number_of_rides_starting_at_station
 FROM (
  SELECT start_station_id, COUNT(*) number_of_rides
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` AS trips 
  GROUP BY start_station_id
) AS station_num_trips
INNER JOIN
`bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations` AS stations
ON station_num_trips.start_station_id = stations.station_id 
ORDER BY number_of_rides DESC
```

The `trips` is not recognised on the inner join so you have to use your subquery alis `station_num_trips` to join with